# Communicate 2 linux ec2 in private vpc having one ec2 in public subnet and one in private

Tags: amazon-web-services

So i am trying to build a private vpc having a private and a public subnet. I want to communicate 2 linux ec2 machines with each other within same vpc. Also please explain inbound and outbound rules with ACLs in simplest way.

[image: security group description]

[image: ssh into ec2]

Answer (score 0):

If both Amazon EC2 instances serve the same function (are operationally the 'same'), then:

- Create a **Security Group**
- Add in **Inbound Rule** on the security group permitting access from the Security Group (itself) on the desired port number
- Attach the Security Group to both instances

This will allow both instances to communicate with each other because **security groups are applied to each instance *individually***, so the Inbound Rules must permit access from 'itself'.

If the EC2 instances serve *different* purposes, (eg one is an app server, one is a database server):

- Create a Security Group on the App server (`App-SG`) with desired inbound permissions from the Internet
- Create a Security Group on the Database server (`DB-SG`) with inbound permissions on the desired port from `App-SG`

That is, `DB-SG` specifically refers to `App-SG` when defining inbound permissions.

**Do not modify ACLs** in the VPC unless you have a very specific reason for limiting network access (eg creating a DMZ).

Comment: Hi, John thanks for your help. I am still struggling with the security group. I add custom tcp with port 22 and destination as security group but now even I can't get access to ec2.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to SSH from one instance to the other? What is the error when you use `ssh -vvv` debugging output? Are both instances attached to the same security group? Please note that you should be configuring the INBOUND security group setting. Leave the outbound configuration as the default "Allow All". You mention "destination", which seems wrong.

Comment: Yes, John, I assign security group to the source in inbound rule and attach that security group to both the instances and I ssh both instances separately through my local machine then ping ip of other instance but that didn't respond, though they respond to internet.

Comment: Ping requires additional rules in the Security Group. Getting Ping to work does not mean that SSH will work, so it is better to concentrate on getting SSH to work. | The 2nd picture in your question is an attempt to connect via SSH -- is this from your own computer, or is it from one of the EC2 instances? If it is your own computer, you need to add an additional Inbound Rule in the security group to permit access from _your_ computer. If it is showing an EC2 instance, then **connect via the private IP address of the target instance** (_not_ the Public IP address).

Comment: Yes, I ssh into both instances with my local computer.

Comment: @HimanshuPal I'm confused about your situation. It should be possible to SSH from one instance to another instance in the same VPC if you are connecting to the **private IP address** of the instance and the security group has an Inbound rule permitting the IP address range, and the outbound rules permit all access. The picture in your question shows you as using the **public IP address**, which might be causing your problem.

Comment: Thanku so much for your help. I will be glad to be in contact with you on LinkedIn.